# Removing noise coming from 3.5mm audio jack

Tags: audio, speakers

I see there is a question similar to this [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26262/constant-stream-of-distortion-noise-from-3-5mm-jack). However its solution was not for everyone, and doesn't help me. Any time a key is pressed either remotely through ssh or directly connected there is a noticeable click sound from the speakers like the information is being processed. Also when i install something or run a program that displays text it will make a louder noise from the other background noise. I already tried going into config.txt to make some changes i read about but that doesn't help at all. Is there something i can change here on the pi or do i need to settle with an hdmi to aux adapter. Also my speakers are 3W 4 Ohm and i heard there may be problems with low impedance speakers to begin with but i will try and report any solution.

Comment: I think using USB sound card, and digital power amp might be more quiet. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96756/how-can-i-amplify-my-voice-in-real-time-just-like-a-microphone-does

Comment: You can't, use a USB sound card or HDMI. See my explanations of the output circuit for why that is the case https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/72599/71180

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have embedded noise sallying your acoustic pathway.

The ultimate solution is to have an isolated sound card installed on your GPIO header. An isolated sound card breaks any chance of currents flowing from the Pi through the acoustic pathway. For that reason, as no noise can flow to your acoustic pathway, you will not hear the embedded noise any more.

Probably the highest quality sound will be when the isolation is just after the GPIO header. In this case the isolation is between the Pi and the audio codec.

Some sound cards are well designed and don't require complete isolation, however it can be a case of purchase and test to find out.